# IIS 8.5 error on targetFramework 4.5.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, iis-8.5, target-framework

I've a problem on windows server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5. My asp.net application, go error on webconfig line 

like Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'.

.NET Framwework 4.5.2 installed and application pool from iis are using NET CLR v.40xxx

Any idea why ?

Comment: Please, share the snippet of *web.config* and the error message.

Comment: Image of error: https://mega.nz/#!lFMmkCpD!FRUAU1YtsfkWEuPXLPqD8F85g8H3TXmUWwpwPVSMt0U

Comment: Sorry it's Italian Lang.

The 'targetFramework' attribute in the <compilation> element of the Web.config file is displayed only as the target .NET Framework version is 4.0 or later (for example, '<compilation targetFramework = "4.0">'). The 'targetFramework' attribute refers to a version of the .NET Framework that is later than the one installed. Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version.

Comment: Had you enable IIS before you install the .NET Framework 4?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the .NET Framework 4 before you enable IIS, you need to run the [ASP.NET IIS Registration tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) in order to register the .NET Framework with IIS using following syntax:

```
aspnet_regiis -iru
```

**Note**, you should use correct version of *aspnet_regiis* utility. The location where the tool is installed depends on the .NET Framework version. See link above.